# If $E|X_i|^{2}\rightarrow0$, $\frac{S_n}{n}\xrightarrow{p}0$ is not always true.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We know $E|X_i|^{2}\rightarrow0 \implies X_n\xrightarrow{p}0$. Proof: using Chebyshev's inequality, $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)<\epsilon^{-2}E|X_n|^2\rightarrow0$.

Let $S_n = \sum_{m=1}^{n}X_i$. Since we do not have restrictions on $X_1, X_2, ...$, I can construct a counterexample by letting $X_1=c, c\in\mathbb{R}, c>0$. Obviously, $\frac{S_n}{n}$ would not converge to $0$ in probability at this point. Is this a correct idea?

Comment: What are $X_2, X_3, \dots$ in your counterexample? It's possible that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges to $0$ even if $X_1$ is the constant $c$; for example, if all the other random variables are identically $0$, then $\frac{S_n}{n} = \frac cn$.

Comment: You're right. If I let $X_n=1$ for all $n$, then $\frac{S_n}{n}=1>0$. I think that is good enough.

Comment: But then you don't get $E|X_i|^{2}\rightarrow0$

Comment: That's true... This question seems harder than I initially though . It seems to me that I can't satisfy $E|X_i|^2\rightarrow0$ without assuming that $X_i=0$ for all $i$. If that's the case, I am starting to be convinced that the statement is true.

Comment: NB: the $L^2$ convergence is quite important here. If $X_n$ converges almost surely or in $L^p$ (for $p\ge1$), then so does its Cesàro sum $\frac{S_n}n$. However, regarding convergence in probability, this is not true in general! The convergence $\frac{S_n}n\stackrel{\mathbb P}\to0$ cannot simply follow from $X_n\stackrel{\mathbb P}\to0$.

Answer (score 3):

It is true, because
$$E\,\left\lvert\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}n\right\rvert^2\le\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nE\,|X_i|^2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$
by Jensen's inequality and Cesàro-Stolz theorem, and because convergence in $L^2$ entails convergence in probability.